# What is inner kernel in context of BLAS libraries

Tags: parallel-computing

I was reading about BLAS (Basic linear algebra subsystem) and I frequently encountered the term "inner kernel". What does it mean by "inner kernel"?

Comment: The "heart" of the system, which is used to implement the library.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a little more?

Comment: It was just a guess, based on the meaning of "kernel".